# RNN Encoder Decoder using keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build an architecture which will be used for machine language translation (from English to French)

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape =(15,1)))

model.add(RepeatVector(output_sequence_length))

model.add(LSTM(21,return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(french_vocab_size, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Max length of English sentence is 15 and that of French is 21. Max number of English words is 199 and that of French is 399. `output_sequence_length` is 21.
This model throws me an error

Error when checking input: expected lstm_40_input to have shape (None, 15, 1) but got array with shape (137861, 21, 1)

I am stuck with the understanding of the LSTM in keras.

1.The first argument according to documentation must be 'dimensionality of output space'. I did not understand what that means. Also,

2. what exactly happens `return_sequences` is set to True

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Kind of data are you trying to feed your network ? Because it seems to me that you didn't convert your words to vectors (binary vectors or encoded vectors).

Anyway, a LSTM Netword need a 3 dimensional entry, the dimensions correspond to that : (samples , timesteps , features).

In your case, samples correspond to the numebr of your sentences, I guess 137861. Timesteps correspond to the length of each sequence, which In your case is 15, and features is the size of each encoded word ( Depending on which type of encoding you choose. If you choose OneHotEncoding, it will be 199).

The error that you got shows that you fed your network sequences with 21 timesteps instead of 15.

For your second question, when return_sequences is set to False, it returns only one output per LSTM layer, which in your case will be (256, ) for your first LSTM layer. when it's set to True, it will have one output per timestep, giving you an overall output of shape (15 , 256). When you want to stack two or more LSTM layers, you always have to set the first layers to return_sequences = True.

Also, what you are building is called a Many to Many architecture, with different timestep lengths for the input and the output (15 vs 21). As far as I know, it's not that easy to implement in keras.

Comment: I have tokenized the english sentences and I'm feeding them as the input. Each input is a sentence (converted in vector format and padded to make them of even length, i.e., 15)

Comment: i don't understand this! if i do `model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape =(21,1)))
    model.add(RepeatVector(output_sequence_length))
    print (model.input_shape)
    model.add(LSTM(15,return_sequences=True))
    print (model.input_shape)
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(french_vocab_size, activation='sigmoid')))
    print (model.summary())` , i get the error Wrong input shape. Found input shape (None, 21, 1) using parameter input_shape=(137861, 15, 1) and *

Comment: *if i do `model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape =(15,1)))
    model.add(RepeatVector(output_sequence_length))
    print (model.input_shape)
    model.add(LSTM(15,return_sequences=True))
    print (model.input_shape)
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(french_vocab_size, activation='sigmoid')))
    print (model.summary()) ` i get the error `Error when checking input: expected lstm_13_input to have shape (None, 15, 1) but got array with shape (137861, 21, 1)`. Please note the input_shape parameter and the three dimensional parameter in the error. I am confused